# Migration disabled: vhost-user backend lacks VHOST_USER_PROTOCOL_F_LOG_SHMFD feature

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, virsh

#### I tried this command on the host.

```
virsh snapshot-create-as --domain test_vm_back --name "snapshot-before-install-package" --description "snapshot test"
```

As you know, this is just a simple command from tutorials to create a snapshot of the VM.
The VM is running.

## ERROR from the command.

I googled this error, but I couldn't understand it. This problem seems rare.

```
error: Requested operation is not valid: cannot migrate domain: Migration disabled: vhost-user backend lacks
VHOST_USER_PROTOCOL_F_LOG_SHMFD feature.; Migration disabled: vhost-user backend lacks VHOST_USER_PROTOCOL_F_LOG_SHMFD
feature.; Migration disabled: vhost-user backend lacks VHOST_USER_PROTOCOL_F_LOG_SHMFD feature.; Migration disabled:
vhost-user backend lacks VHOST_USER_PROTOCOL_F_LOG_SHMFD feature.; non-migratable device:
0000:00:03.1:00.0/vhost-user-fs; non-migratable device: 0000:00:03.0:00.0/vhost-user-fs; non-migratable device:
0000:00:02.7:00.0/vhost-user-fs; non-migratable device: 0000:00:02.6:00.0/vhost-user-fs
```

#### Host's `df -H` result

```
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                          4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                             7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             3.1G  121M  3.0G   4% /run
/dev/mapper/rl-root                70G   40G   31G  57% /
/dev/mapper/backup_vg-01_lv   3.4T  2.1T  1.2T  65% /mnt/external_lvm_drive01
/dev/mapper/backup_vg-02_lv  9.3T  8.2T  673G  93% /mnt/external_lvm_drive02
/dev/mapper/rl-home               387G  3.0G  384G   1% /home
/dev/sdc1                        1014M  408M  607M  41% /boot
tmpfs                             1.6G   56K  1.6G   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                             1.6G   76K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

#### `journalctl -f` result

```
Jan 15 23:14:27 localhost.localdomain polkitd[989]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:575281:207674108
(system bus name :1.5042 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --process 575281 --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path
/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jan 15 23:14:27 localhost.localdomain polkitd[989]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:575281:207674108
(system bus name :1.5042, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected
from bus)
```

#### a Linux distro

Host and the client are both Rocky OS 9.

#### Host's `uname -a` result:

`Linux localhost.localdomain 5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.0.1.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 28 18:44:09 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

#### Client's `uname -a` result:

`Linux localhost.localdomain 5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.0.1.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 28 18:44:09 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

#### Host's `virsh dumbxml --domain test_vm_back`

```
<domain type='kvm' id='2'>
  <name>test_vm_back</name>
  <uuid>ae58c4a4-9103-4103-90c6-30772a45635e</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://redhat.com/rhel/9.0"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit='KiB'>2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>2097152</currentMemory>
  <memoryBacking>
    <source type='memfd'/>
    <access mode='shared'/>
  </memoryBacking>
  <vcpu placement='static'>3</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-rhel9.0.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none' migratable='on'/>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/test_vm_back.qcow2' index='2'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='sata'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='sata0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='qemu-xhci' ports='15'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'>
      <alias name='pcie.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='1' port='0x10'/>
      <alias name='pci.1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='2' port='0x11'/>
      <alias name='pci.2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='3' port='0x12'/>
      <alias name='pci.3'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0x13'/>
      <alias name='pci.4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='5' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='5' port='0x14'/>
      <alias name='pci.5'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='6' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='6' port='0x15'/>
      <alias name='pci.6'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='7' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='7' port='0x16'/>
      <alias name='pci.7'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x6'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='8' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='8' port='0x17'/>
      <alias name='pci.8'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='9' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='9' port='0x18'/>
      <alias name='pci.9'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='10' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='10' port='0x19'/>
      <alias name='pci.10'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
      <driver type='virtiofs'/>
      <binary path='/usr/libexec/virtiofsd'/>
      <source dir='/mnt/external_lvm_drive01/jupyter-config'/>
      <target dir='jupyter_shared'/>
      <alias name='fs0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x07' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </filesystem>
    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
      <driver type='virtiofs'/>
      <binary path='/usr/libexec/virtiofsd'/>
      <source dir='/mnt/external_lvm_drive01/task'/>
      <target dir='task_shared'/>
      <alias name='fs1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x08' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </filesystem>
    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
      <driver type='virtiofs'/>
      <binary path='/usr/libexec/virtiofsd'/>
      <source dir='/mnt/external_lvm_drive01'/>
      <target dir='external_lvm_drive01_shared'/>
      <alias name='fs2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x09' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </filesystem>
    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
      <driver type='virtiofs'/>
      <binary path='/usr/libexec/virtiofsd'/>
      <source dir='/mnt/external_lvm_drive02'/>
      <target dir='external_lvm_drive02_shared'/>
      <alias name='fs3'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x0a' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </filesystem>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:46:24:b8'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet1'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/1'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='unix'>
      <source mode='bind' path='/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/domain-2-test_vm_back/org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
      <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0' state='disconnected'/>
      <alias name='channel0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input2'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>
    <audio id='1' type='none'/>
    <video>
      <model type='vga' vram='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
    <rng model='virtio'>
      <backend model='random'>/dev/urandom</backend>
      <alias name='rng0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x06' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </rng>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'>
    <label>+107:+107</label>
    <imagelabel>+107:+107</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to the problem.

After I remove virtiofs(but a enabled shared memory doesn't prevent snapshot.) in the xml file which exists in `/etc/libvirt/qemu`, I can do a snapshot.

#### git diff

```
diff --git a/test_vm_back.xml b/test_vm_back.xml
index c54de19..3397add 100644
--- a/test_vm_back.xml
+++ b/test_vm_back.xml
@@ -109,30 +105,6 @@ or other application using the libvirt API.
     <controller type='sata' index='0'>
       <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
     </controller>
-    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
-      <driver type='virtiofs'/>
-      <source dir='/mnt/external_lvm_drive01/jupyter-config'/>
-      <target dir='jupyter_shared'/>
-      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x07' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
-    </filesystem>
-    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
-      <driver type='virtiofs'/>
-      <source dir='/mnt/external_lvm_drive01/torrent'/>
-      <target dir='torrent_shared'/>
-      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x08' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
-    </filesystem>
-    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
-      <driver type='virtiofs'/>
-      <source dir='/mnt/external_lvm_drive01'/>
-      <target dir='external_lvm_drive01_shared'/>
-      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x09' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
-    </filesystem>
-    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
-      <driver type='virtiofs'/>
-      <source dir='/mnt/external_lvm_drive02'/>
-      <target dir='external_lvm_drive02_shared'/>
-      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x0a' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
-    </filesystem>
     <interface type='bridge'>
       <mac address='52:54:00:46:24:b8'/>
       <source bridge='br0'/>
```

After fixing it, do not forget `virsh define --file /etc/libvirt/qemu/test_vm_back.xml`